# INSERT INTO SELECT with multiple CASE WHEN

Tags: sql-server, insert, case

I am trying to insert into table using select from another table with multiple case scenarios. Each person has more than one value, which gives multiple rows in the jointable. I want to select col2 based on col1 from the jointable.

The outcome so far, is 3 line of same person, 1 of the 3 values in each row.

See result here

[image]

```
INSERT INTO #temp (Name, WageNo, Tiltraedelses_dato, Jubilaeum ,Sabbatical, Anciennitet)

SELECT 
 e.FirstName, 
 e.WageSystemKey, 
 e.[StartDate],
CASE WHEN v.EmployeeCustomColumnId = 2 THEN v.Value END,
CASE WHEN v.EmployeeCustomColumnId = 3 THEN v.Value END,
CASE WHEN v.EmployeeCustomColumnId = 1 THEN v.Value END

FROM Employees e
LEFT JOIN EmployeeCustomValue v on e.EmployeeId = v.EmployeeId

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Comment: col1 col2? What does your expected result look like?

Comment: I would expect 1 row inserted with each and single of the 3 values.
Like if you merged the three rows in the attached image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a group by with conditional aggregation, something like this

```
INSERT INTO #temp (Name, WageNo, Tiltraedelses_dato, Jubilaeum ,Sabbatical, Anciennitet)

SELECT 
 e.FirstName, 
 e.WageSystemKey, 
 e.[StartDate],
max(CASE WHEN v.EmployeeCustomColumnId = 2 THEN v.Value END),
max(CASE WHEN v.EmployeeCustomColumnId = 3 THEN v.Value END),
max(CASE WHEN v.EmployeeCustomColumnId = 1 THEN v.Value END)

FROM Employees e
LEFT JOIN EmployeeCustomValue v on e.EmployeeId = v.EmployeeId
group by  e.FirstName, 
 e.WageSystemKey, 
 e.[StartDate]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of other ways to go about this.

```
INSERT INTO #temp (Name, WageNo, Tiltraedelses_dato, Jubilaeum ,Sabbatical, Anciennitet)

SELECT 
e.FirstName, 
e.WageSystemKey, 
e.[StartDate],
v2.Value,
v3.Value,
v1.Value

FROM Employees e
LEFT JOIN EmployeeCustomValue v1 on e.EmployeeId = v1.EmployeeId and v1.EmployeeCustomColumnId = 1
LEFT JOIN EmployeeCustomValue v2 on e.EmployeeId = v2.EmployeeId and v2.EmployeeCustomColumnId = 2
LEFT JOIN EmployeeCustomValue v3 on e.EmployeeId = v3.EmployeeId and v3.EmployeeCustomColumnId = 3
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO #temp (Name, WageNo, Tiltraedelses_dato, Jubilaeum ,Sabbatical, Anciennitet)

SELECT FirstName, WageSystemKey, [StartDate], 
MAX(Jubilaeum) AS Jubilaeum, MAX(Sabbatical) AS Sabbatical, 
MAX(Anciennitet) AS Anciennitet
FROM (SELECT 
e.FirstName, 
e.WageSystemKey, 
e.[StartDate],
CASE WHEN v.EmployeeCustomColumnId = 2 THEN v.Value END AS Jubilaeum,
CASE WHEN v.EmployeeCustomColumnId = 3 THEN v.Value END AS Sabbatical,
CASE WHEN v.EmployeeCustomColumnId = 1 THEN v.Value END AS Anciennitet

FROM Employees e
LEFT JOIN EmployeeCustomValue v on e.EmployeeId = v.EmployeeId) AA
GROUP BY FirstName, WageSystemKey, [StartDate]
```